# Problem AmCharts5 label wrapping and error code showing up

Tags: amcharts

To truncate the labels on my chart -as per https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/wrapping-and-truncating-axis-labels/
I copy the code

```
// Configure axis label
var label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
label.wrap = true;
label.maxWidth = 120;
```

and it kills the chart. (surely this should be standard from AmCharts- who ever wants overlapping labels)

I also get an error underneath the chart (when showing or not showing the chart itself)

} catch( err ) { console.log( err ); }

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
// Configure axis label
var label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
label.wrap = true;
label.maxWidth = 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a confusion between amCharts versions. In fact, I think you are trying to inject **amCharts 4** code in **amCharts 5** logic. This will not work.

If you want to *wrap* or *truncate* your labels using amCharts 5, you will have to use their `oversizedBehavior` property which is documented here: [ILabelSettings – amCharts 5 Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/ilabelsettings/#oversizedBehavior_property). This property depends on another one: `maxWidth`.

I give you a complete example below.

```js
am5.ready(function() {

  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {});
  
  xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
    oversizedBehavior: "wrap", // You can replace it with "truncate".
    maxWidth: 100, // Play with it and see what happens...
    textAlign: "center"
  });

  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "category",
    renderer: xRenderer
  }));

  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));

  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    categoryXField: "category",
    valueYField: "value"
  }));

  var data = [
    {
      category: "First category",
      value: 1337
    },
    {
      category: "Second category",
      value: 42
    },
    {
      category: "Third category",
      value: 1970
    }
  ];

  xAxis.data.setAll(data);
  series.data.setAll(data);

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```